# Execute a command line from a service's Execute thread

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, service, delphi-7

At first glance I'm having no luck with

```
uses ShellApi;

...

ShellExecute(Handle, pchar('open'), pchar('emf2pdf.exe'), 
             pchar(s), pchar(root), SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

where s is the parameter string and root is the directory where the command is located.

The error I get is 'missing operator or semicolon', and also 'too many actual parameters'.

Probably something easy I overlooked, bit stressed. Not even sure where to get the Handle from.

Be happy for alternative ways of executing a command line that you can suggest! Basically the service looks for files to convert at regular intervals, so I'm just looking for a way to form a command line such as in DOS and execute it, preferably without a window popping up briefly and closing, but I'll take what I can get. :)

My correct installation of Delphi can code-hint the parameters for me, but not popup a help page on pressing F1 (not found in index).

Update: Used this CreateProcess function from DelphiPages:

```
Function ExecuteAndWait(sExecutableFile : String; wWindowState : Word = SW_SHOWNORMAL) : Boolean;
var
siInfo : TStartUpInfo;
piInfo : TProcessInformation;
begin
    FillChar(siInfo, SizeOf(siInfo), #0);

    with siInfo do begin
    cb := SizeOf(siInfo);
    dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    wShowWindow := wWindowState;
    end;
    Result := CreateProcess(NIL, pChar(sExecutableFile), NIL, NIL, FALSE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NIL, pchar(ExtractFilePath(sExecutableFile)),siInfo, piInfo);
    if Result then
    WaitForSingleObject(piInfo.hprocess,INFINITE);
end;
```

And then called it with this commandline, which works when pasted in 'cmd' but not with this code:

```
ExecuteAndWait('D:\EMF2PDF\emf2pdf.exe -append 0 -margin 36x36x36x36 -width 595 -height 420 "D:\EMF2PDF\EMF\example.emf" "D:\EMF2PDF\PDF\example.pdf"');
```

I'd be happy if you could supply (link to) a working example call (in a service) of the console app commandline above.

UPDATE:
The command in question opens no window but types stats of the conversion in console. I use the software downloadable here: http://www.verydoc.com/emf-to-pdf.html

Also, I was not informed until now that the server in question is a virtual server, if that makes a difference.

Checked just now, and when I try out my service I'm logged in as a remote session user. Wouldn't the service be able to at least create a process that calls emf2pdf when Windows is running with a logged in user?

If you can think of alternative solutions to using the Verydoc software, any at all, under these conditions or other, on this server (such as a batch user) I'd love to try them!

Comment: 1. Did you try from a standard app? What happens there? Don't try to debug this from the service until it works from a standard app. 2. What value does `s` have and what value does `root` have? 3. What OS are you working on. If you are on Vista or up, you need not worry about any Windows appearing from a service.

Comment: 1. That runs fine from a normal Application, however the same codeline pasted into the Execute thread doesn't even compile as mentioned above. 2. s=misc switches specific to the emf2pdf command, root='D:\EMF2PDF'. 3. Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, 64-bit.

Comment: Some things are unclear for me. Is your service which call `CreateProcess` runs under System account? You want to run the `emf2pdf.exe` on the some user's desktop. How you identify the user? Can use impersonate it for example? Which information you know to identify the session of the user? Another question: do you want to have the process `emf2pdf.exe` running under the service credentials or under the user credentials?

Comment: No, I don't *want* to run it on some user's desktop. But it seems necessary? Because there's no proper shell in Windows. As for credentials, it only needs to r/w files to a temporary folder. The service runs under a local system account, and any user on this virtual server will get a notification (from "Desktop 0"?)

Answer (score 1):

A service runs inside another session and hence another win station so you cannot use ShellExecute beacuse the service win station has no shell at all; there might not be a logged in user etc etc. The only but is an interactive service but those are not supported anymore on the newer Windows version (from Vista and above if I recall correctly).

As David mentioned in the remarks below: it should be possible to start a process using:

```
ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'sleep.exe', '60', '', SW_HIDE);
```

I tested it with a different program and it failed so it might depend on the application you wish to start so apparently this answer is incorrect. It still gives some insight information so I will leave it here unless someone asks me otherwise.

Comment: I didn't know that. I must admit I'm slightly surprised. You ought to suggest the alternative which is to use `CreateProcess`.

Comment: In fact this answer is incorrect. It is perfectly possible to call `ShellExecute` from a session 0 isolated service. I have just done so. Certainly if the app in question attempts to show UI then there will be problems. But, per se, there is nothing to stop you using `ShellExecute` from a service.

Comment: @David: The call itself is not impossible, it will however not start an executable without any additional code. I do not think not mentioning CreateProcess makes the answer incorrect albeit possibly not complete enough. Do you have a link or something to support your claim in the remark above? I am interested to see what you do to get  applications running correctly from a service without resorting to whole slew of system calls to set the process up correctly.

Comment: What is incorrect is your statement that ShellExecute cannot be used from a service. I just did `ShellExecute(0, 'open', 'sleep.exe', '60', '', SW_HIDE);` from `ServiceStart` of a vanilla Delphi service app. `sleep.exe` is a simple Delphi console app that calls `Windows.Sleep`.

Comment: @David: I am amazed, I did it and it failed (no process was created or at least not visible in Process Explorer), probably it depends upon the process started.

Comment: What process did you try to start? I intentionally chose one that did practically nothing (no chance to get caught out in session 0 hurdles) and ran for a decent length of time.

Comment: Be happy to accept CreateProcess as answer, if you can give enough information to write the code line to do it as if I'd type the commandline in question in 'cmd'. NB: Updated the question, see the current snag with CreateProcess.

Answer (score 0):

Your update to the question reports that the call to `CreateProcess` works when run from a standard app but fails when run from a service. The issue is surely related to session 0 isolation of services. With this information, I can think of the following explanations:

1. In the context of the service, the `D:\EMF2PDF\...` path is not available. Check that you can create and open a text file here to see whether or not this diagnosis is true.
2. Session 0 isolation is just incompatible with the `emf2pdf` program. If that is so then you will need to find another program to do the conversion. That might be hard to do because it a program that processes EMF is liable to use GDI commands and they are very likely to fail in the context of a service.

By far the easiest solution will be to run this process as a standard application. I can see that this might not be a palatable prospect for what appears to be a server service.

Comment: 1. This works, as the log file from which I cut the full commandline passed to CreateProcess is written fine there. 2. Do you mean I could write a standard Delphi app (which calls emf2pdf using f.ex. ShellExecute) and call that with parameters from the service? Could I use another "mediator", such as writing a .bat file and call that from the service using CreateProcess? What about DETACH_PROCESS and CREATE_NEW_PROCESS flags?

Comment: In that case I'd bet that 2 is the hurdle.

Comment: that was fast! Accidental Enter press, added comment to 2.

Comment: Your problem, I believe, is that you can't run `emf2pdf` from inside session 0. You need A) Abandon using a service, or B) Find a converter that works in session 0 or C) Start the process in an interactive session. C) is probably not much of an option since on a server OS you typically don't have interactive sessions. Even if you can go down this route it's very very hard to do: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2009/07/14/launching-an-interactive-process-from-windows-service-in-windows-vista-and-later.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same problem here. We were also generating a PDF with a command-line tool.

If you look at the properties of your service in the services dialog, you can see a checkbox on the 'logon' tabpage. The checkbox is titled 'Allow service to interact with desktop'. Set this to checked.

One of the answers here indicates that this is no longer possible on newer Windows versions, but it works just fine on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 server.

Edit: The setting in the properties of the service may have changed it's meaning, I don't know about that. But it solved our problem. Our commandline tool for generating PDFs run just fine after checking this checkbox.

Comment: Excellent, given that there must then be something wrong with my call. What parameters did you use for CreateProcess? I can run the conversion commandline fine from command prompt/console, seconds after the service tried to do so and nothing happened.

Comment: "One of the answers here indicates that this is no longer possible on newer Windows versions, but it works just fine on Windows 7 and Windows 2008 server." I don't agree with that.

Comment: My understanding of that setting on Vista and up is that it allows the service to interact with a hidden desktop in session 0. So the setting no longer does what it did in XP and allow service to interact with the logged in user's desktop. That what is meant by saying it does not work in Vista. That said, it's plausible that it will solve the problem at hand here.

Comment: Got it working with ShellExecuteEx... now, how to make the Interactive Services Detection manageable? :) SW_HIDE...possible?